# The word "joint" as a synonym for place?

Tags: synonyms

I'd like to know in what context can the word "joint" be used as a synonym for place.

Is it used for places that sell products and/or services?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a very common and informal way to refer to a business, usually one that sells food or drink. "I run a burger joint in Anchorage." "Lets meet at that joint on the corner of 5th and Main." Usually it will refer to a small, casual restaurant or bar.

Comment: There's also even less formal use to refer to any place whatsoever, and use with the definite article to refer to jail.[¹](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=joint&defid=482345)

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that one. *The* joint is jail.

Comment: In my experience, *joint* is definitely more likely to be used of a retail outlet if it sells *food/drink* rather than, say, clothes or newspapers. It also tends to imply that the establishment is ***small***, and that whatever they sell is either consumed ***on the premises***, or it's "fast food" consumed immediately after purchase. Finally, I also think there's a terndency for *joints* to be ***places where people meet***, rather than just places that sell things.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - That comment would make an A-1 answer, imo.

Comment: @J.R.: While I was writing my comment, Bob was composing what seems to me a perfectly good answer (not that I can really fault Jolenealaska's, so far as it goes). Of course, there are other contexts, such as [*casing the joint*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22casing+the+joint%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) where the referent might be, say, a ***bank*** (or indeed some wildly figurative usage where "the joint" isn't even a physical thing at all, let alone a place where people meet, sell things, or whatever).

Comment: @FumbleFingers We need one answer to rule them all!

Comment: Interesting answer and comments. Looking for examples that contradict my generalizations, I don't see any clear ones. Burger joint is interesting, though; seems a combination of frowned upon and facetious. Frowned upon because we feel rather guilty about our (over)eating habits--I've never met an American who is literally "starving", and rarely heard one say he was just hungry--and our propensity to spend vast amounts of money to avoid cooking for ourselves; facetious because hey, nothing wrong with eating, after all.

Comment: As for "casing the joint", it's an example of "bad guys" putting it all backwards. "The joint" is where you go to have a good time; banks and mansions and the like are where all those pillars of society keep all of the ill-gotten gains they use to keep the little guy under their collective heel.

Answer (score 8):

The word *joint* has lots of meanings, but the relevant OED definition here is...

> **joint** 14 a. slang or colloq. (chiefly US).
>    *A partnership or union, or a place of meeting or resort, esp. of persons engaged in some illicit occupation; spec. (in America) a place illegally kept (usually by Chinese) for opium-smoking, an opium-den; also applied to illicit drinking-saloons.
>
>    More generally, a place; a house.*

OED also note separately the now somewhat dated (also mainly US) slang usage ***the*** joint = prison. They don't specifically say how these usages arose in the first place, but I think it probably turns on the "core" definition *joint = the place or part at which two or more things are joined or fitted together; a **junction.*** That's to say, a place where *people meet socially* (not necessarily to smoke opium or cannabis [**joints**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_%28cannabis%29)).

---

In general, *joint* is definitely more likely to be used of a retail outlet if it sells food/drink rather than, say, clothes or newspapers. It also tends to imply the establishment is *small*, selling food/drink consumed on the premises, or "fast food" consumed immediately after purchase (still in the vicinity of other customers).

So yes, *joints* often "sell things". But usually they're places people go to as much for social interaction as for the products/services they actually buy (such as  licensed premises, coffee shops, burger bars, etc.). If a domestic residence is referred to as "So-and-so's joint", you can probably assume people often use it as a meeting place to see *each other*, not just to visit whoever lives there.

There's also the idiomatic [***case the joint***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/case+the+joint) *(look over an establishment, usually with intent to rob)*, but I can't really see how that relates to the more general usage. It seems to be something of a "one-off".

Answer (score 4):

It's a slang term, referring to a place where people gather to socialize and engage in activities that are slightly frowned upon in society.  Good examples are a bar, a pool hall, or perhaps a casino.  Very often, the term is used facetiously: "come on over and hang out at my joint" would be an invitation to come visit me at home.

"The joint" is also a slang term for prison, probably as a sarcastic reference to the meaning I have described above.

See [definition 3 in this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/joint).

[edit] after reading all the notes, I see I hadn't thought of "burger joint, pizza joint" when I was making my answer. So, "casual eating place" is another pretty distinct definition. [/edit]

Also see [Fats Waller's "This Joint is Jumpin"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dv2ktr-yc3o), from 1943.

Comment: I like this answer, although it should be noted that the term goes a little broader than this. _This is my favorite pizza joint_ doesn't suggest shaky morality, just really good pizza.

Comment: I like definition 3 [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/joint) better. In my experience, usage comes without implications against the moral character of the establishment. Incidentally, I've never heard anyone refer to their own residence this way. "Crib" or "pad" would be more likely, I think.

Comment: @J.R. After I wrote my comment I had the thought that there might be some bleed-over from [“clip joint”](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/clip-joint), but I still agree that the noun alone isn't strong enough to denegrate a place's respectability.

Comment: The morality implication probably stems from *gin joint*, a name for speakeasies during prohibition. I don't think that implication carries over at all when we refer to that place on the corner as a *joint*.

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say that "joint" is used for places that are "frowned on by society". I think it's more like, for places that are considered extremely casual. A place that sells pizza may be called "that pizza joint". I've never heard someone call a gourmet restaurant "that French joint" except as a joke. A place where people play pool and listen to a garage band may be "the pool joint"; a place where they hold Bible studies and listen to hymns is not called "a hymn joint" -- again, except as a joke. But few think there's anything immoral about playing pool or eating pizza.

Comment: @jay: why didn't you include "slightly" in your quote? I put it there. Furthermore, why do you equate "slightly frowned upon" with "immoral"?  I surely don't.  Ok, moving on.  Now, I don't disagree with the idea of extremely casual places, but there are places that are extremely casual that aren't joints, too.

Comment: @J.R.: I would say that the term goes more broadly due to its often-facetious use. Perhaps the distinction is eroding faster than all the dictionaries are keeping up with, however. See also my note to Jolene's answer above.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to add the "food joint" definition. Here I will say this as well, however: if I may speak bluntly, we Americans find our eating habits rather disreputable. If we didn't, we wouldn't try to unconsciously justify eating by saying we are "starving" instead of "hungry". A "food joint" is a place where you will probably eat enough food to feed a half a dozen for a day in, say, Kenya. And if you "break down" and order that foot-high piece of Fudge volcano chocolate cake, too, then throw in a whole birthday party of 3 year olds on top of that.

Comment: @Jay [facetiously, in case it isn't clear]: those fancy French places aren't really joints, no. They're so stingy with their servings that I'm still hungry when I leave. See, we Americans are only hungry *after* we eat. Otherwise, we're "starving." :)

Comment: @BobRodes Okay, maybe "immoral" was too strong a word. As you say, it's possible that the word started out meaning seedy but came to be applied as a joke to places that were merely casual, so often that the humorous connotation has been lost and that is now routine usage.

Comment: @BobRodes And sure, when I say I'm "starving", I am describing a condition that the average Kenyan would probably refer to as "just finished eating".

Answer (score 1):

A common informal usage of joint meaning place is "let's blow this joint" to mean "leave this place,"  It is not used to mean "smoke this marijuana cigaraette".

Comment: "Let's blow this joint" is _frequently_ used to mean "lets smoke this marijuana cigarette."!

Comment: When I was a kid, it meant either one.

Comment: Only Bill Clinton would say "Let's blow this joint" in relation to marijuana, because he didn't inhale.  Anyone else would refer to sucking on a joint.